# How to write a remove function (from a binary tree) simply and clearly?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, pattern-matching, binary-search-tree, racket

This is an assignment. But it was [already] due and I think I worked it out. I'm new to Racket. I feel my code is a bit tedious. Is there any better way to improve it?

The requirement supposes to give a key `x`, and `k` is the value of the root node. If `x < k`, return recursion on left subtree + `k` + right subtree. If `x > k`, return recursion on right subtree + `k` + left subtree. If `x=k`, **(a)** return right subtree if left is empty, **(b)** return left subtree if right is empty, or otherwise **(c)**  return right min value + left subtree + (right subtree - min value):

```
(define (delete x tree)
  (match tree
    [(emp) (emp)]
    [(node k lt rt)
     (cond
       [(< x k) (node k (delete x lt) rt)]
       [(> x k) (node k lt (delete x rt))]
       [else
        (cond
          [(equal? lt emp) rt]
          [(equal? rt emp) lt]
          [else
           (define (get-min tree)
             (match tree
               [(emp) (emp)]
               [(node k (emp) (emp)) k]
               [(node k lt (emp)) (get-min lt)]
               [(node k (emp) rt) k]             
               [(node k lt rt) (get-min lt)]))
           (node (get-min rt) lt (delete (get-min rt) rt))])])]))
```

The following is the given tree structure. We should not modify it.

```
; The empty tree is represented by an "emp" record of 0 fields.
(struct emp () #:transparent)

; A node is represented by a "node" record of key, left child, right child.
(struct node (key left right) #:transparent)

; BST insert.
(define (insert x tree)
  (match tree
    [(emp) (node x (emp) (emp))]
    [(node k lt rt)
     (cond
       [(< x k) (node k (insert x lt) rt)]
       [(< k x) (node k lt (insert x rt))]
       [else tree])]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the structure predicates, in particular `emp?`: instead of `(equal? lt emp)` (which is also erroneous, `emp` should be in parens), use just `(emp? lt)`.

When a function is too long, it's a sure sign it should be broken into smaller functions.

Lastly, the removal and reporting of the minimum element of a tree should be done in one function, with one tree traversal. `delete` is too broad, it is searching for the element it was given; but here we *already know* the element will be at the leftmost position:

```lisp
(define (delete x tree)
  (define (join lt rt)        ; all values that are in lt 
    (cond                     ;   are less than those in rt
      [(emp? lt) rt]
      [(emp? rt) lt]
      [else (call-with-values             ; use rt's minimum value  
              (lambda () (min-elem rt))   ;  as the new top node's
              (lambda (k tree)
                (node k lt tree) ))])) 

  (define (min-elem tree)     ; tree is guaranteed to be non-empty
     ; a less efficient mock-up; better if done with one traversal
     (let ([minval (get-min tree)])
       (values minval (delete minval tree))))

  (define (get-min tree)      ; leftmost value in a non-empty tree
    (match tree
      [(node k (emp) _) k]           
      [(node _ lt _) (get-min lt)])) 

  (match tree
    [(emp) (emp)]
    [(node k lt rt)
     (cond
       [(< x k) (node k (delete x lt) rt)]
       [(> x k) (node k lt (delete x rt))]
       [else    (join lt rt)])]))            ; removing the top
```

It is the responsibility of  `min-elem` to return *both* the minimal element *and* the valid tree that's left after its removal (see  [`values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29), and [`call-with-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29),  for that; if that's too taxing / confusing at first, you can indeed implement it as you showed in the question, with `get-min` and the recursive use of `delete`, it's just will be less efficient that way ... *update: added the simpler implementation to the code*).

The minimal element is going to be the *leftmost* one in the tree (which is guaranteed to be non-empty). There are only two cases to consider: whether the tree's left child is empty, or not. You don't need to handle all the cases explicitly as you do. It is unnecessarily verbose.

Also, in your description (and in the code), you've got the branches flipped at places: *left* is *always* going on the left, recursion or no recursion. It should be:

> If x < k, return *recursion on left subtree* + k + *right subtree*. If x > k, return *left subtree* + k + *recursion on right subtree*. If x=k, (a) return *right subtree* if left is empty, (b) return *left subtree* if right is empty, or (c) otherwise return *left subtree* + right min value + *(right subtree - min value)*.

Comment: Yea I know. But the assignment seems not allow us to split the function. And also the leftmost element is usually the smallest. But in our case, it may not be the value that we want. Look at this case: ```(define t (node 50 (node 40 e (node 45 e e)) (node 60 e (node 70 e e))))```  40 should be the min value. But If we do remove 50, then we have to go to the right subtree. Then 60 is the value that we want.

Comment: if we remove the top (50), we indeed go to the right child, and we then remove *its* leftmost element. which *is* 60. which will become the new top. that code goes on the dots I left for you to complete. :)

Comment: Is ```(node 60 e (node 70 e e))``` the right child? If so, 60 is the root element. And it has no element on the left.

Comment: ```emp```should be in parens. Why? If so, should I rewrite ```[(emp? lt) rt]``` as ```[((emp)? lt) rt]```?

Comment: `emp` is the constructor. try `emp` at the prompt. try `(equal (emp) emp)` at the prompt. as for the code, I already wrote it in the answer. :) here's what happens: defining the structure gets you automatically defined the constructor `emp` and the predicate `emp?` such that `(emp? (emp))` returns `#t`. same for node: `(node? (node 1 2 3))` returns `#t`.